# Absolute sequence unbounded within radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of the complex power series $a_nz^n$ with $0<R<\infty$. Show that if $|z|>R$, then the sequence $|a_nz^n|$ is unbounded.

Trying by contradiction:

So suppose it is bounded: $|a_nz^n|<M$ for some $M$ for all $n$. Then I want to show that this leads to the sequence partial sums of $|a_nz^n|$ being bounded and hence converging, i.e. $|z|<R$, and so proving the contrapositive.

I'm not sure how assuming boundedness helps me proceed because the partial sums of $|a_nz^n|$ up to $N$ are less than $MN$ but this diverges.

Furthermore, would this method work - would I need to consider $|z|=R$ also?

Comment: Show: If $\lvert a_n z^n\rvert \leqslant M$ for all $n$, then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert r^n$$ converges for all $0 \leqslant r < \lvert z\rvert$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the sequence is bounded and let $r$ such that $|z|>r>R$ then
$$|a_n r^n|=|a_nz^n|\left(\frac{r}{|z|}\right)^n\le M \left(\frac{r}{|z|}\right)^n$$
and the geometirc series $\sum_n\left(\frac{r}{|z|}\right)^n$ is convergent which leads to a contradiction.

Obviously this method doesn't work for $|z|=R$ and notice that in the border of the disc of convergence we may found convergence or divergence of the series.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. So don't we have to consider the case $|z|=R$ for completeness? How would you go about that? Or can it just be disregarded?

Comment: What we can say about these series: $\sum_n\frac1{n^2} z^n$ and $\sum_n nz^n$ for $|z|=1$?

Comment: These two series have the same radius of convergence $R=1$ but the sequence $\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ is convergent so bounded but the sequence $(n)$ is divergent.

Comment: So we cannot say anything when $|z|=R$?

Comment: Yes we can't say anything and we should treat every case separately.

Comment: Well done, S--- (oops): user!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a_n z^n$ is bounded by $M \geq 0$ and let $w \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|w| < |z|$. Then $|a_n w^n| = |a_n z^n| \cdot |(w/z)^n| \leq M \cdot |w/z|^n$.

Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |w/z|^n < \infty$ as $|w/z| < 1$ (geometric series).

By the comparison test, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n w^n$ converges (absolutely) for all $|w| < |z|$, which implies that the radius of convergence is at least $|z|$.

For $|z| > R$ we derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose that the sequence $(|a_n z^n|)$ is bounded. Let $R'=\frac{R+|z|}{2}$. If $|w|\le R'$, then $\sum a_n w^n$ converges.